# Getting UiImage from CgContextRef and pass it to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I want to get the UIImage out of CGContextRef, and show it on UIImageView in a different UIViewController

So for this, I have written this code, I m writing this code, when I close my drawingview, because I have made my drawing view as a subview of UIViewController

//mydrawingView.m

```
- (void)closeButtonClicked
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO,0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    m_curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    ViewController *table = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [table setImage:m_curImage]; 
    [table viewDidLoad];
}
```

///myViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{   
    IBOutlet UIImageView *m_imageView;
    UIImage *image;

}
```

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

///myViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    m_imageView.image = image; 

    NSLog(@"%@", m_imageView.image);
}
```

But I am not able to show this image on UIImageview,

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Hello friends, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out the answer for this question, to get the image out of the canvas , the above code applies and to show it on a imageView of anotherViewController, we have to implement delegate protocol method.

Regards
Ranjit